# TFS 2015 vNext - Build agent went ilde after update 2

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Updated the TFS server from RTM to release 2 . All looks went fine. But not able to queue builds anymore. when checked the [Build agent it shows red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIKCg.jpg) , and status idle.   Restarted TFS server didn't help. Thanks !!

Comment: I deleted the build agent & pool and created again. now its working. Looks like in TFS 2015 RC2 version,  for configuring the build agent  powershell script is replaced with configureagent.cmd. Also weird thing is    must run RunAgent.cmd and it should be open and running always to enable build agent.